# Задача про устойчивые браки - ошибка (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, списки

Цель: переженить между собой мужчин/женщин наиболее эффективным образом (т.е. с учетом их предпочтений)

> На вход подается список списков, в котором 1 элемент число n =
>   количество мужчин/женщин/пар, 2 элемент - список списков предпочтений
>   мужчин в порядке убывания, 3 элемент - список списков предпочтений
>   женщин так же в порядке убывания. Изначально все мужчины неженаты.
>   Создается список мужчин (от 0 до n - 1), мужчина делает предложение
>   первой женщине из его списка предпочтений. Женщина принимает
>   предложение в случае если она не замужем или претендент стоит в списке
>   ее предпочтений раньше мужа.Если женщина не соглашается, мужчина
>   делает предложение следующей женщине из его списка предпочтений.Шаги
>   повторяются до тех пор, пока не останется неженатых мужчин (да и
>   женщин, соответственно). (отдельное примечание: однополых браков
>   задача не предусматривает, женщины предложений мужчинам не делают)

Мой код:

```
def stableMatching(n, menPreferences, womenPreferences):
    unmarriedMen = list(range(n))
    manSpouse = [n - 1] * n
    womanSpouse = [n - 1] * n
    while unmarriedMen:
        he = unmarriedMen[0]
        hisPreferences = menPreferences[he]
        for she in hisPreferences:
            herPreferences = womenPreferences[she]
            currentHusband = womanSpouse[she]
            if currentHusband == (n - 1) or \
                    (currentHusband != (n - 1) and
                     herPreferences.index(he) < herPreferences.index(int(*currentHusband))):
                womanSpouse[she] = [he]
                manSpouse[he] = [she]
                unmarriedMen.remove(he)
                if (currentHusband != (n - 1) and
                        herPreferences.index(he) < herPreferences.index(int(*currentHusband))):
                    unmarriedMen.append(currentHusband)
                break
    result = sum(manSpouse, [])
    manSpouse = result
    return print(manSpouse)
```

На нескольких тестах отрабатывает нормально:

```
stableMatching(3, [[2, 1, 0], [1, 2, 0], [2, 0, 1]], [[2, 1, 0], [2, 1, 0], [0, 1, 2]])
stableMatching (1, [ [0] ], [ [0] ])
stableMatching(2, [ [0,1], [1,0] ], [ [0,1], [1,0] ])

[2, 1, 0]
[0]
[0, 1]
```

Однако, если в первом тесте на вход подам немного измененные данные, например в первом элементе [[2, 1, 0], **[1, 2, 0]**, [2, 0, 1]] изменяю средний элемент списка [2, 1, 0], **[0, 2, 1]**, [2, 0, 1]] получаю ошибку:

```
line 7, in stableMatching
    hisPreferences = menPreferences[he]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

в чем проблема?

Comment: Ну так выведите на экран текущее значение `he` и посмотрите...

Comment: @Akina я выводила. В первом тесте по очереди передается 0, 1, 2 , в последнем - то же самое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас списки xSpouse, постепенно превращаются из list of integer, в list of list of integer. Естественно, в некоторый момент, их элементы оказывается невозможным использовать для индексного доступа.

Comment: я извиняюсь, но не очень поняла ... в первом и последнем тесте кол-во элементом в списке и кол-во элементов в списках списков одинаковое, типы данных на входе одинаковые, значения варьируются и там и там от 0 до 2, почему тогда в первом случае все ок, а во втором возникает проблема?

Comment: В проблемном случае, срабатывает второе условие if, которое модифицирует список unmarriedMen, добавляя в него list of integer из xSpouse. В первом, успешном случае, это условие не срабатывает, список не модифицируется, ошибка не возникает.

Comment: Вы были абсолютно правы! Большое спасибо за помощь!)